# using UIToolBar for blur effect will reject app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiblureffect

I have an app which need support from iOS 7 and up & I wanna use blur effect at some places.

I know apple have introduced blur view but that supports only iOS 8 and up.

As a solution for iOS 7, the only solution is to use UIToolBar, however I have read before that if anyone use toolbar for blur effect, Apple is rejecting the application.

Did anyone face this issue?

I need one solution that will work in all for blur...

Comment: I also read that Apple reject... but I think now they are accepting...

Comment: The best solution is to drop iOS 7 and set minimum deployment target to iOS 8.0. There's only 6% of users who's using iOS 7 till date. Worth to skip those oldies.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: dropped iOS7... client sauid ios 9 is important...